# How to clear all contents of a file

Tags: buffers

To clear a file I find myself doing something like:

- 1G
- 1000cc (or some large number)

Is there a simpler way to do this for clearing a file? On a normal text editor I normally would do `Cmd-A` and then start typing.

Comment: I usually do `:%d`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ggdG`

`gg`: Move to the first line in the file

`d`: Delete

`G`: [until] last line in file

From help:

```
G           Goto line [count], default last line, on the first
            non-blank character linewise.  If 'startofline' not
            set, keep the same column.
            G is one of the jump-motions.
...
gg          Goto line [count], default first line, on the first
            non-blank character |linewise|.  If 'startofline' not
            set, keep the same column.
```

Substitute `d` with `c` if you want to be in insert mode instantly.

Comment: thanks for this. Is there a way to do this without copying the text into the buffer (I have stuff in the buffer I'd like to 'keep')

Comment: @David542 What do you mean? How can you clear all contents of a file *and* keep some of the stuff in your buffer? Also, what do you mean by *"copying the text into the buffer"*?

Comment: Ah I think you mean the *register*! The default register, right? So that if later you paste with `p` or `P` it will put the previously yanked text... Well, for that, use `gg"_dG`, which deletes it into the [black hole register](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quote_).

Comment: @filbranden yes exactly, thanks for the tip! And thanks again for all your helpful feedback/answers/etc on my questions.

Answer (score 10):

Fastest is

```
:%delete
```

Which can be abbreviated to

```
:%d
```

The `%` is a range standing for “whole file.”

If you want to use a particular register (e.g., black hole):

```
:%d_
```